# why I can't receive the props properly

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx

Note that this question is tagged [next.js](/questions/tagged/next.js). Familiarity with Next.js is *essential* for understanding the relationship between the `getStaticProps` and `Home` functions in the code below.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const dummyData = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'john'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Tom'
    }
  ];
  return {
    props: { data:dummyData }
  };
}

export default function Home({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>USER</li>
      {data && data.map((user) => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          {user.name}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I try to send data to the `Home` function using `getStaticProps`, but when I `console.log` it, it shows `undefined`.

I want to receive the data from getStaticProps().

Comment: Should be working. Is this code in a files in the pages folder?

Comment: [getStaticProps isn't supported in the new App router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#old-methods), perhaps you should switch to the modern approach for data fetching instead of trying to get the old way to work.

Comment: @Quentin thanks bro, i wasn;t realised it until you told me, i use the APP router. Now i know getStaticProps isn't supported anymore . Huge Thanks

Comment: Oh, I assumed you weren't using the app router because, when I did and tried to use getStaticProps, I got a big error message about on the terminal where I was running the Node app and you didn't mention getting one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You just declared the Home component, but you haven't called and passed the value to it yet.
At place you call component **Home**, you must pass value for data like this

```
<App>
  <Home data={[1,2,3,4]} />
</App>
```

Comment: `Home` is, presumably, a **page** component and not one that is called as a child of another component. The Next.js framework is responsible for calling it and passing props to it, not the developer.